# Transformation Constraint

Tags: constraints

Is anybody aware of a comprehensive 'Dummies' guide for the Transformation Constraint? I'm having a real problem figuring out how it works.

Specifically with converting rotations - I'm trying various ways to utilise the Transforms so rather than a specific function I need to be able to have a full explanation of the Constraint in order for me to figure out the cleanest way to achieve a task.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need two objects, an object that will be the controller, another that is controlled and that has the constraint. In the *Map From* field you choose what transformation of the controller will be taken into account, here its movement on Y. In the *Map To* field you choose how it will affect the object that has the constraint. Here, X Source > Y means that the rotation on X will be affected by the Y location of the controller. The values in *Min* and *Max* tell how much it will affect. If you enable *Extrapolate* the transformation will be able to go further:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. The problem is that once an item is an angle to the target it gets confusing to know how to set up the constraint - even when using the 'local space' options the result isn't what's required. That's why I really need a comprehensive overview of how the constraint woks, still really appreciated though, Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and explain what you mean by "once an item is an angle to the target"?

Comment: I apologise - both object's rotation values are not at right angles to each other, they are rotated at different angles so they are not aligned in 3D space with the consistency shown in the example kindly provided above. That's where I'm having quite a few issues. Thanks

Comment: @K.Cee so maybe you should show a precise example, just edit your original post and put some drawings etc?